# Функция выводит только 0,а должна числа от х до 0

Tags: r

```
zad1<-function(x){
    if(x==0) {
        return(0)
    }
    else {
        print((zad1(x-1)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ибо работает рекурсия в этом месте:

```
print((zad1(x-1)))
```

Функция `print` не сработает, пока не завершится функция `zad1`, а она завершится только тогда, когда значение `x` будет `0`, что вы в итоге и получаете на экране.

Вам следует явно показать `x` на экране, пример кода:

```
zad1 <-function(x){
    if(x == 0) {
        return(0)
    }
    else {
        print(x)
        return(zad1(x-1))
    }
}

zad1(0)
print('--')
zad1(1)
print('--')
zad1(2)
print('--')
zad1(3)
```

Вывод:

```
[1] 0
[1] "--"
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] "--"
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] "--"
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 0
```

Comment: Все работает,спасибо!

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ как "решение" вопроса.